# Is it possible to create a Freemarker macro programmatically?

Tags: java, freemarker, ninjaframework

Freemarker is used as the default template engine in the ninja web framework. The framework assigns some default values to a template which are globaly available when using the ninja web framework. I have created an extension for the template which does enbales CSRF-Protection. The extension offers a function which can be used in a template, e.g.

```
${foo(bar)}
```

At the moment the function needs to be called with specific parameters, which is not very intuitiv. Using a macro I could simplify this call to

```
@{foo}
```

and the user doesn't need to worry about passing the correct (e.g. "bar") parameter. But to make this available in the ninja web framework I have to define a macro programmatically. Is that possible?

**UPDATE**

Sorry for the confusion. Meant <@foo/> instead of @{foo} ...

Looking at the Freemarker documentation I maybe can make more clear what I want to achieve: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html

Like I explained above I am passing a custom function to the template, enabling me to call

```
${foo("bar")}
```

What I want to do, is call this via a macro like

```
@<myMacro/>
```

But the defined macro like

```
<#macro myMacro>
  ${foo("bar")}
</#macro>
```

should not be defined in the template but programmatically. Hope that makes it more clear.

**UPDATE2 / SOLUTION**

I ended up using the recommended TemplateDirectiveModel.

```
public class TemplateEngineFreemarkerAuthenticityTokenDirective implements TemplateDirectiveModel {
    private String authenticityToken;

    public TemplateEngineFreemarkerAuthenticityTokenDirective(Context context) {
        this.authenticityToken = context.getSession().getAuthenticityToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Environment env, Map params, TemplateModel[] loopVars, TemplateDirectiveBody body) throws TemplateException, IOException {
        if (!params.isEmpty()) {
            throw new TemplateException("This directive doesn't allow parameters.", env);
        }

        if (loopVars.length != 0) {
            throw new TemplateException("This directive doesn't allow loop variables.", env);
        }

        Writer out = env.getOut();
        out.append(this.authenticityToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's `<@myMacro/>`, not `@{myMacro}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeMarker macro invocations doesn't look like `@{...}`. Is that some kind of Ninja-specific extension?

Anyway, if you know that there's a `bar` in the data-model, then your method can get it like `Environment.getCurrentEnvironment().getDataModel().get("bar")`, so it need not be passed in.

Also, it's maybe useful to know that FTL has two kind of "subroutines", the function-like ones, and the directive-like ones. Both can be implement both in FTL (`#function`, `#macro`) and in Java (plain Java methods, `TemplateMethodModelEx`, `TemplateDirectiveModel`). The real difference is that the function-like ones are for calculating values, and the directive-like ones are for printing values directly to the output (hence bypassing auto-escaping) and for side-effects. But all of these can reach the `Environment`, so there's no difference there.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I think thats not quiet what I want to achieve, so I updated my question.

Comment: My answer basically says that you can use a `TemplateDirectiveModel` instead of a macro.

Comment: I did try it with the TemplateDirectiveModel, but I can't figure quiet out on how to handle an empty TemplateDirectiveBody (body is null) as I just call

<@myDirective/>

Comment: What's there to handle? You want an empty body, so it should be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

You can call a macro "dynamically".  Let's say you had a macro:

```
<#macro myMacro>
  ${foo("bar")}
</#macro>
```

You can call it like this:

```
<@myMacro />
```

*OR*

```
<@.vars["myMacro"] />
```

So then you can do...

```
<#assign someVar = "myMacro" />

<@.vars[someVar] />
```